# Does Imagemagick have functions to redraw/distort images to the various map projections? ie mollweide, mercator, orthographic

Tags: imagemagick, projection, cartography

I searched the Imagemagick documentation for this but could not find references to standard geographical map projections. There are other applications that do this, but not with IM's level of precision. "Matthews Map Projection software" is a good example. I wish to use IM in a script to demonstrate these projections applied to fictional world maps.

It seems such a natural thing for IM to cover. Considering all the other distortions available, maps would be right up its alley. example projections: mercator, mollweide, orthographic, gnomonic...

link to MMPS
http://www.users.globalnet.co.uk/~arcus/mmps/

Comment: Imagemagick does not have any direct transformation/distortion to map projections. You would have to code that as either a very slow -fx computation or using displacement maps.

Comment: You can write C code for -process function to create your own Imagemagick Filters for such map projections. I have done that for projecting onto a sphere (similarity to gnomonic) and onto cylinders as well as for fisheye distortions and undistortions. See https://imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php#filters and https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#process

Comment: Thank you @fmw42 , adding your suggestions to my search terms turned up this request from 2012:  https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=21383    Cartographic projections are not a new wish list item it seems. I will read more about -fx and displacement maps. Is there an official feature request protocal for IM? 2012 was 7 years ago. Was it deemed to be not within IM's scope or design philosophy?

Comment: You can request enhancements on the Developer's forum at https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/. It was likely simply put on a list of enhancements, but at a low priority due to time limitations of the developers, who have full-time jobs and because bug fixes are higher priority. As I mentioned, you can write your own Magick Filters in Imagemagick. Also the person who developed most of the distortion code and resampling code has retired from the team. Imagemagick is open-source, so anyone can contribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IM does not have cartographic projection functions yet. 
Other open source software can suffice. 
Matthews Map Projection Software
http://www.users.globalnet.co.uk/~arcus/mmps/
And xplanet
http://xplanet.sourceforge.net
Have command line options that are scriptable.

Displacement maps, the -fx function, and the -process function are other avenues.

Comment: Perhaps you can ask Matthew to port or offer his code to Imagemagick.